# django-background-task - A specific kind of task are not running whereas other tasks still run

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have been using django-background-task for a while but the last background-task function I just added is not working.

I created a new backgroud_task as below in a marketplace/tasks.py

```py
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=1)
def background_pair_new_account(lv_external_id: str, lv_siren: str, lv_vat_number: str, lv_pack: str) -> None:

    print(lv_external_id, lv_siren, lv_vat_number, lv_pack)
```

The background task is called as below:

```py
from marketplace.tasks import background_pair_new_account

background_pair_new_account("12345678", "789234678", "FR01789234678", "full")
```

The background task is well created in backend:

| TASK NAME | TASK PARAMS | RUN AT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| marketplace.tasks.background_pair_new_account | [["12345678", "789234678", "FR01789234678", "full"],{}] | 28 juillet 2021 09:59 |

But when I run `python manage.py process_tasks`, my task doesn't run. However the other tasks still works.

What are the reasons why a task would not run even if the execution date is passed, the task is not locked and no error is mentionned ?